# Friend Function calling Static Members of Derived Classes. Not getting expected output

Tags: c++, static, friend

My first post here :)

I am having a problem with the following C++ code. I have an ABC class A, and two derived classes B and C. All of them have a static member called id:

```
using std::cout;

class A
{
private:
    friend int bar(A& a);
    static const int id = 1;

    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class B : public A
{
private :
    friend int bar(A& a);
    static const int id = 2;

    void foo() { /*Do something*/ }
};

class C : public A
{
private:
    friend int bar(A& a);
    static const int id = 3;

    void foo() { /*Do something*/ }
};

int bar(A& a)
{
    return a.id;
}

int main()
{
    B b;
    C c;

    cout << bar(b) << "\n";
    cout << bar(c) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting this code to print out 2 and 3 - rather it prints out 1 and 1 (bar() is always using A::id). What am I doing wrong? Any ideas?

---

Based on the comments below, this the final code I am using. It works, but would love to hear more thoughts :)

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

class A
{
private:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class B : public A
{
private:
    template <typename T>
    friend int bar(T& t);

    static const int id = 2;
    void foo() { /*do something*/ }
};

class C : public A
{
private:
    template <typename T>
    friend int bar(T& t);

    static const int id = 3;
    void foo() { /*do something*/ }
};


template <typename T>
int bar(T& t)
{
    return t.id;
}


int main()
{
    B b;
    C c;

    cout << bar(b) << "\n";
    cout << bar(c) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your declaring `bar` as a friend, but it has no meaning in this code.

Comment: @Jesse In my actual code id is private - which makes no difference to the output. I have changed the post above :)

Comment: Right, friend functions grant permission to access private and protected members of a class, however, to achieve what you want you have to make bar a member of A, B and C as the answer suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to avoid writing `int foo() { return id; }` for all the derived classes?

Yes, using templates. For example:

```
template <typename T>
int foo (T& x)
{
    return x.id;
}
```

However, if `id` is private, this doesn't reduce the code by all that much.

Comment: @ahmadh: Well, one thought is, instead of declaring a friend function, declare a member that returns the id and call that member in the function template, i.e. `return t.getid()`.

Answer (score 2):

`a.id` will be defined at compile-time as `A::id`. You would need to define a virtual member (non-static) function in class `A` and have it overridden in `B` and `C` to return their respective `id`s and call this function in `bar`.

Comment: Note that the term you want isn't _overloading_ but _overriding_: the former refers to functions with different signatures being chosen at compile time while the latter refers to different functions with the same signature (or, in some other languages than C++, contra-variant arguments) which is chosen at run-time.

Comment: @Dmitry I have edited the original post after reading your comment.